# Vuejs all assigments are by reference even with spreading objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, variable-assignment

If the template is:

```
<div id="app">
  <button @click="doEditing">Edit</button>

  <input v-if="editing" v-model="editing.profile.name" />
  <span>{{ user.profile.name }}</span>
</div>
```

And Vuejs app is:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    user: {name: 'Foo'},
    editing: null
  },
  methods: {
    doEditing(){
       this.editing = {...this.user};
    }
  }
})
```

even `this.editing = {...this.user};` which is spreading object, assigns it by reference. So when I edit the input, `v-model` changes `this.user`, which is not what I expected.

I also have tested `Object.assign`, but no chance.

Comment: Works fine for me. When I type something into the `<input>` it changes `editing` but leaves `user` unchanged.

Comment: What if you first clone user object and then spread?

Comment: @skirtle I missed to mention it's a deeper object like `user.profile.name`.

Comment: data should be a function - https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function

Comment: @BrianGlaz I see, but this isn't the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lodash `_.cloneDeep` function just solved the problem.